# How to automatically click on the "Accept cookies" button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How can I automatically click on the Facebook "Allow all cookies" button? I can't find the part of the code useful for clicking. The link is this https://www.facebook.com/privacy/consent/user_cookie_choice/?source=pft_user_cookie_choice

> NOT A LINK: To view the cookie button, you must be logged in with Facebook, because there is a cookie button both before logging in and after logging in. In this case it is the cookie button after login

My code instead this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-visualcompletion="accept_button"]'))).click()
```

I wrote "`'button[data-visualcompletion ="accept_button"]'`, but the error is this.

HTML CODE
[image]

Comment: I don't find the cookies consent Can you update the question with the relevant HTML please?

Comment: @undetected Selenium  The link is correct. To view the cookie button, you must be logged in with Facebook, because there is a cookie button both before logging in and after logging in. In this case it is the cookie button after login

Comment: Do you have a set of demo creds to login?

Comment: @undetected Selenium Unfortunately not :(

Comment: @undetected Selenium I added a html screenshot of the buttons to the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To click on the *Allow all cookies* button you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Consenti tutti i cookie'] span span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Consenti tutti i cookie']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: I imagine this probably works but I have a question about the first option. Why the need for `span span`? If it finds the div, shouldn't it send the click to the center of that element which would indirectly click the underlying span(s)? At least that's how I understand it should work but it clearly doesn't because I used a similar approach in my answer except I left out the span elements and someone already mentioned it doesn't work. Just curious if you know why those extra two span elements make a difference.

Comment: @tehbeardedone As per [Selecting Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAFBe.png) a space then `span` would select a multilevel descendant `<span>`. Similarly the first span have multiple descendant and our desired element is the `<span>`

Comment: @undetectedSelenium it doesn't work

Comment: You should use "button" instead of span, it does the trick. (Also, you obviously have to translate the text)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you found that locator because that element is not a button from what I can tell. I see two options for finding this element.

[image]

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='Allow all cookies']")

# or

ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath(span[contains(text(), 'Allow all cookies')])
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score -3):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/privacy/consent/user_cookie_choice/?source=pft_user_cookie_choice')
WebDriverWait(driver, 86400).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')).click()
```

Comment: This will only work until they change the structure of the page and then it will break. It's only a temporary solution.